# Is the "laptop ban" for flights from Turkey to the UK in force?

Tags: air-travel, uk, turkey, electronic-items, british-airways

Last year the UK government implemented a ban on electronic devices for the flights from Turkey, Lebanon, Jordan, Egypt, Tunisia, and Saudi Arabia.

- [How does the UK electronics travel ban affect my travel without check-in luggage?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96470/how-does-the-uk-electronics-travel-ban-affect-my-travel-without-check-in-luggage)
- [How strongly is the recent "laptop ban" enforced on flights to the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92882/how-strongly-is-the-recent-laptop-ban-enforced-on-flights-to-the-uk)

After a while this ban was [revoked](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/changes-to-uk-aviation-security) for some airports. In addition, I had a flight from Istanbul to London with Turkish Airlines last month. I didn't have any issue with my laptop.

Tomorrow I have a flight again, but with British Airways this time. During the online check-in I noticed [this news](https://www.britishairways.com/travel/flightops/public/en_us?p_faqid=5709), which was updated a few days ago.

> **Hand baggage restrictions for electronic items on flights from some
>   countries**
>
> Answer Id 5709    **Updated 15/05/2018** 02.21 PM (UK time) Summary
>
> British Airways is complying with additional UK Government security
>   requirements on flights TO the UK FROM the following countries:
>
> - Egypt
> - Jordan
> - Lebanon
> - Saudi Arabia
> - Tunisia
> - Turkey (British Airways operates from Atatürk airport in Istanbul)

The government [website](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/electronic-devices-and-electrical-items) says (without any timestamp):

> **Flights to the UK from Turkey, Lebanon, Jordan, Egypt and Saudi Arabia**
>
> There are specific restrictions for flights to the UK from these
>   countries.
>
> You do not need to follow these restrictions if your flight is from
>   Antalya, Bodrum, Istanbul Sabiha Gökçen or Izmir airports in Turkey,
>   or from Luxor, Hurghada or Marsa Alam airports in Egypt. Follow the
>   restrictions for all other flights to the UK instead.

Since my flight is from Istanbul Ataturk Airport (IST), it is not exempt from the restrictions (in case the information is valid). My search on Google News didn't return any recent news relevant, so I got confused.

Is the ban in force again or do British Airways still apply the restrictions from the last year?

Comment: You've listed two fairly definitive sources, both of which state that the extra security restrictions are in place.  Why would you think that it is not?

Comment: @Doc The UK Government website doesn't make any distinction between Turkish Airlines and British Airways, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: OK, I see your point. I've updated my answer, but basically TK and PC (Pegasus) have been specifically exempted from the rules.

Comment: @Doc That makes sense. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these restrictions are still in effect.

For reference see this [UK Government Website](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/electronic-devices-and-electrical-items), and this [British Airways website](https://www.britishairways.com/travel/flightops/public/en_us?p_faqid=5709).

(Yes, those are the same 2 websites listed in your question - but they are both about as definitive as you can get that the restrictions are still in place!)

The restrictions do not apply to Turkish Airlines and Pegasus airlines as they have instigated additional screening measures which the UK government has approved (which is why you'll normally see these flights depart from a fixed few gates, such as gate 218 at IST)

Comment: [This article](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/uk-laptop-ban-flights-istanbul-turkey-pegasus-turkish-airlines-ataturk-izmir-airports-electronic-a7865296.html) I just found seems related to your last paragraph, you may consider adding it as a source. I'll accept your answer anyway.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "instituted"?  *Instigate* implies goading or urging someone else to some (usually negative) action.

Comment: @phoog https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/instigate